# filtering through table of fortnight dates for end of month values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a table of values matched to fortnightly dates like this:

> 1/1/17                    3123
>
> 15/1/17                   3422
>
> 29/1/17                   3645
>
> 12/2/17                   3941

and I want to extract values to a new table for the end of each month, taking the value of the last date in that month if not available.

eg.

> 31/1/17                   3645

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MATCH function, like this.

```
Private Sub TestMatch()

    Dim Dt As Date

    Dt = CDate("1/5/16")
    Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng(Dt), Range("Dates"), 1)
End Sub
```

Where "Dates" is a column of dates sorted in ascending order, and `Dt` is the first day of the month following the month of the date of which you wish to extract the last available day.